# combination of functions are not working properly

Tags: sql, oracle

When i try to fetch the results using below function I'm getting only first string available under SH_CHGDESC which is FRTRV-1

string available for the SH_CHGDESC are: FRTRV-11;SFARV-13;SCRRV-12

want to fetch all available strings

```
If InStr ({pipe.SH_CHGDESC}, "1;") >0
then mid({pipe.SH_CHGDESC},1,InStr ({pipe.SH_CHGDESC}, "1;")-1)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: That isn't Oracle syntax. And it isn't clear what you are trying to do really, or what you want to happen. Do you have a single string with semicolon-delimited values that you want to split into multiple values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just trying to split a delimited string into multiple values; with your string in a CTE:

```
with pipe (SH_CHGDESC) as (
  select 'FRTRV-11;SFARV-13;SCRRV-12' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(sh_chgdesc, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
from pipe
connect by level < regexp_count(sh_chgdesc, '(.*?)(;|$)');

REGEXP_SUBSTR(SH_CHGDESC,'
--------------------------
FRTRV-11
SFARV-13
SCRRV-12
```

If you are getting the string from the table and working with multiple rows at once then it's a bit more complicated, but can be handled if there is a primary/unique key on the `pipe` table.